# Enum and Generic constant specific method

Tags: java, enums

I have an enum like:

```
    enum TEST {
        TEST1, TEST 2;

        public abstract <T> String stringify (T input);
    }
```

I need to add a constant specific method , something like stringify.

This method will take different types of inputs (for each enum). Can I do that? Eclipse is not letting me do it ..something like:

```
enum TEST {
    TEST1(
       public <Float> String stringify (Float input){
          return String.valueOf(input);
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: 1.How would you call this method?_______ 2.Does your code really pass the function as a constructor argument, or did you mistype the braces?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it with `enum`s, but you can simulate this behaviour with generic class:

```
public abstract class TEST<T> {
    public static final TEST<Float> TEST1 = new TEST<Float>() {
        public String stringify (Float input){   
            return String.valueOf(input);   
        }
    };

    public abstract <T> String stringify(T input);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do it. but it's not clear what the benefit is:

```
enum TEST {
    TEST1 {
        public <Float>String stringify(Float input) {
            System.out.println("TEST1");
            return String.valueOf(input);
        }
    },
    TEST2 {
        public <Integer>String stringify(Integer input) {
            System.out.println("TEST2");
            return String.valueOf(input);
        }
    },
    TEST3 {};
    public <T>String stringify(T input) {
        System.out.println("super");
        return "";
    }
    public <Integer>String stringify2(Object input) {
        System.out.println("non generic");
        return String.valueOf(input);
    }
}
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(TEST test:TEST.values()) {
            System.out.println(test.stringify(new Float(1.23)));
            System.out.println(test.stringify(new Integer(42)));
            System.out.println(test.stringify(new Double(4.56)));
        }
        for(TEST test:TEST.values()) {
            System.out.println(test.stringify2(new Float(1.23)));
            System.out.println(test.stringify2(new Integer(42)));
            System.out.println(test.stringify2(new Double(4.56)));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of each Enum value as a class.  So yes, the enums can have methods, just like a class does -- they all have the *same* methods though.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Look at the Planet example.

Also note that the enum itself can have static methods....(just like a class)

Comment: I know that...but I want constant specific method with different types on each enum type. In this case if TEST1 is being called with Float, TEST2 might be called with Double.

Comment: @gats, i think the best you can do, looking at your comment from the other answer, is have a static method on the enum itself and do something different based on the enum value.

Comment: @hvgotcodes: This is not correct advice.  One should think of the whole enum declaration as a class.  Each of the constants that makes up the enum becomes an instance of the enum class.  Constant-specific methods are therefore a bit counterintuitiive; it is nice to be able to define constant-specific behavior, but we don't ordinarily think of class instances as having different behavior from other instances of the same class.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't make each enum constant implement an abstract method but require a different type of input than the other enum constants. If you could, what would happen if you were given an instance of your `TEST` enum (you don't know what constant it is) and tried to call `stringify` on it? What type would you pass it?

**Edit:** Given what you've said about these enums being used to decode strings into objects, it seems to me you have several options:

- You could get a `String` representation of each decoded object by just calling `toString()` on it.
- You could add a set of overloaded static method on the enum class itself, called `stringify(Float)` and `stringify(Double)`, etc. Then you could just call `TEST.stringify(value)` and if there were a `stringify` method for the value's type, it'd work fine.

I imagine there are other options as well.

Comment: so the solution is to  pass in Object as the parameter and in implementation, let each enum type cast the input to the type necessary ?

Comment: @gats: Well... no. That wouldn't really be a good idea. Could you edit your question to explain what it is you want to accomplish by doing this? We might be able to suggest a better alternative.

Comment: there is preexisting code in which enums are used to encode String values to a particular type...Now I need to add decode function...

Comment: It is not always toString method. And using overloading I will have to write a lot of methods.

Comment: @gats: You'd have to write a lot of methods if you were doing one per enum constant too, what's your point?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use generics with enums, because the enum constants themselves are already the concrete (singleton) instances. At instance level, the generics must already be concrete.
So, I would stringly recommend going with one of the alternatives given in the other answers.

If you must do it in an enum, you could consider the following, which at least gives you a runtime means of type checking, including ClassCastExceptions. You won't have any support from the compiler though.

```
public enum TestEnum {
    Test1(Float.class),
    Test2(Integer.class),
    Test3(String.class);

    private final Class<?> iInputType;

    private TestEnum(final Class<?> pInputType) {
        iInputType = pInputType;
    }

    public Class<?> getInputType() {
        return iInputType;
    }

    public String stringify(final Object pInput) {
        return String.valueOf(iInputType.cast(pInput));
    }
}
```

Test Code:

```
System.out.println(TestEnum.Test1.stringify(1.23f));
System.out.println(TestEnum.Test2.stringify(42));
System.out.println(TestEnum.Test3.stringify("foo"));
// but:
// System.out.println(TestEnum.Test1.stringify("foo")); // -> ClassCastException!

for (TestEnum test : TestEnum.values()) {
    for (Object input : new Object[]{1.23f, 42, "foo"}) {
        if (test.getInputType().isAssignableFrom(input.getClass())) {
            System.out.println(test.stringify(input));
        }
    }
}
```